# Mac Rechargeable Battery - 13-inch Serial Number

Tags: mac, serial-number

Where are all the places I can locate the serial number for a Mac Rechargeable Battery?  I know the serial number can be located on the battery itself as well as on the Mac they were used with, but is the serial number available in any other locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The battery serial number is recorded in 4 places I have seen:

1. Physically on the battery (and optionally on the box if you purchased the battery in a box as a separate item)
2. In system profiler when the battery is installed in a running mac.
3. I have asked at the genius bar from time to time for them to look and see if there are records from when the mac was built in the factory. From time to time a client needs to know what hard drive or what battery came with a specific mac and that information is sometimes available.
4. Saved to the filesystem - use spotlight to look for files that have the mac's serial number. System profiler will save all hardware as a text/rtf/xml file if asked to. Some crash reports squirrel away a copy of that information so if you look, it might be there even if you didn't save it explicitly.

Comment: ''"Physically on the battery"'': Does this apply to MBA 2011 13"? Where exactly it can be found written physically on the battery?